# WSFC - Unable to set node weight in Failover cluster

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover, quorum

I have a two node Windows failover cluster configured with Always on availability groups which are configured for disaster recovery not for high availability. In this windows failover cluster we are not using quorum/witness, in simple terms cluster is set to use of no witness.

We don't want to use quorum because we are having multi subnet cluster configured with AG, By using the quorum configurations for Manual failover given in MSDN we have configured from below URL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/manage-cluster-quorum#quorum-considerations-for-disaster-recovery-configurations

Current Settings:
No preferred site.
Dynamic Quorum = 1

Node1 is primary and Node Weight(Assigned Vote) =1 and Dynamic Weight(Current Vote) = 0
Node2 is Secondary and Node Weight = 1 and Current Vote = 1

As Node1 is primary I have moved my cluster group resources to Node1 and able to set the node weight property to 1. But while trying to set the Node2 node weight property to 0 it is throwing me an error as below where I am not able to resolve the issue.

Error Message:
Exception setting "NodeWeight": "Unable to save property changes for 'Node2'.
The request is invalid either because node weight cannot be changed while the cluster is in disk-only quorum mode,
or because changing the node weight would violate the minimum cluster quorum requirements"

I have tried to restart the cluster service but didn't fix my error.
I have tried to add a file share quorum witness and then removed still unable to fix the error.

Expected result is:
Node    Assigned vote   Current Vote
Node1             1                1
Node2             0                0

Quorum type should be: Node Majority

Q1. How to avoid this disk-only quorum situation and fix the error?

Any leads to this error is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but why exactly do you try to play with a setting which should be maintained by the cluster itself? Changing Node votes should be used to let cluster run on the last survival node in case of catastrophic failure. So what do you try to achieve?

Comment: I am not playing here, as we have MultiSite configuration, we are using this manual failover configuration mode given by Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/manage-cluster-quorum#quorum-considerations-for-disaster-recovery-configurations

DynamicQuorum = 1, when we are setting the manual configuration, as per this last man stand, this takes care of nodes majority and decide.
DynamicWitness- This is managed by cluster and after failover we set the node weight manually and cluster decides about the voting and majority.

Comment: Edit the question and add details about why you don't (want to) have a witness for tie-breaking.

Comment: @vonPryz, Please you may suggest me how re write the question, 
I am unable to set the node weight property, I have already given my environment and error message which I am receiving, I have given the link which says for manual failover configuration mode on multisubnet we are trying to use this way, and problem is not about why I don' t want witness, problem is why I am able to set node weight on other servers and unable to do it only on this server which has cluster managed voting, there is no forum or blog which doesn't have answer/question like this and this should be a notable question.

Comment: Set-ClusterQuorum -Cluster (Get-Cluster) -NodeMajority also didn't work on this scenario.

Comment: What is the output of `Get-ClusterQuorum | select QuorumType` and what is the output of `Get-ClusterNode | select name, nodeweight, dynamicweight`

Comment: @SeanGallardy, QuorumType is showing as Majority and I have already given in the question about the nodeweight and dynamicweight and expect result but any how I am giving it again. Node1: NW=1 DW=0 and Node2: NW=1 and DW=1 expected result should be Node1: NW=1 DW=1 and Node2: NW=0 and DW=0, for Node2 I am able to set NW as 1 but not able to set 0. Kindly check this and let me know if you have got any answer Why/How is this causing issue with disk only quorum and unable to set to node majority type quorum.

Comment: @info.sqldba, one more question. As by my cluster understanding, you need defined amount of votes to have cluster functional in a proper way. In your case I guess it would be 2 because it's a sum of the votes on your list (Node a 1 and Node B 1). Did you tried to assign 2 to the Node A before you set Node B to 0?